# Remove all files not managed by my script

Tags: salt-stack, file-management

I have a formula that reads in the pillar a list of items to create some config files, like this:

```
fileA
  config:
    - some other config
    - ...
fileB
  config:
    - other configs
```

the problem is, in the parent folder there is a lot of temporary files and other created by the system.

How can I remove all the files not managed by my script? Fot the time being I am doing like this

```
directory_clean:
  file.directory:
    - name: {{ directory }}
    - clean: True
```

But this way all my files are being removed and added again. Is there a better solution?

Comment: you could do a `{% for item not in directory%}..... - name: {{ file }}`.I hope the directory represents all the keys from the pillar file

Comment: `directory` represents a path to a directory, kinda like `/var/logs`, would that solution work for that?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how your salt tree is set up, you should be able to do this with [file.recurse](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.recurse):

```
manage_directory:
  file.recurse:
    - name: /etc/something
    - source: salt://something/files
    - clean: True
    - template: jinja  # if needed
```

This assumes there is a directory in your salt tree containing all and only the files you want.

Comment: but the files are generated from a template, how can I do this?

Comment: If you mean multiple files each from their own template, the template option works with file.recurse too (edited example). If you mean multiple files generated from the *same* template, then it might be more complicated....if you can give an example of the file paths and template paths, that may help.

Comment: Currently we are using like so: pillar has an array of filenames, organizer.sls manage each file from pillar using the same template

Comment: Okay. Yeah, recurse won't work for that. If it's just a matter of not having miscellaneous system files mixed in with the ones you're managing, maybe you could put them in their own folder somewhere else?